# realtime with django web sockets

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I have a question for you please, I have an app with django channels:

THE FIRST QUESTION
the idea is to get all transaction in real time, but the transaction is growing in each moment, example the app is beginning to 10 transactions and before is 100 transactions and more, the app realtime is a little slow, how to do the app to get transactions? maybe one by one transaction if I decided to do one by one, how to implement this function:

my function to get all transaction is:

```
class TransactionConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
async def connect(self):
    self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
    self.room_group_name = 'transaction_%s' % self.room_name

    # Join room group
    await self.channel_layer.group_add(
        self.room_group_name,
        self.channel_name
    )

    await self.accept()

async def disconnect(self, close_code):
    # Leave room group
    await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
        self.room_group_name,
        self.channel_name
    )

# Receive message from WebSocket
async def receive(self, text_data):
    text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
    message = text_data_json['message']

    # Send the message to room group
    await self.channel_layer.group_send(
        self.room_group_name,
        {
            'type': 'list_transaction',
            'message': message
        }
    )

# Receive message from room group
async def chat_message(self, event):
    message = event['message']
    # Send message to WebSocket
    await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
        'message': message
    }))

async def list_transaction(self, event):
    token = event['message']
    message = self.list_trans_all(token)

    await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'massage': message
        }))

 # HERE RETURN ALL TRANSACTIONS BY JWT TOKEN USER LOGGED
def list_trans_all(self, token):
    end_point = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/transactions/list-trans-users/'
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
    listrans = requests.get(end_point, headers=headers)
    return listrans.json()
```

and my client is:

```
<script>
   var typeTransaction = 'buy';

   var transaction_Socket = new WebSocket(
      'ws://127.0.0.1:8001/ws/transaction/' + typeTransaction + '/');

   export default {
          name: 'orders',
          data(){
           return {
             // transaction_datas: '',
          }
     },
      mounted(){
        // console.log(transaction_Socket);  
        // recive msg
        transaction_Socket.onmessage = function(e) {

        var transaction_datas = JSON.parse(e.data);
        console.log(transaction_datas);
       };

     },
     methods:{
        getTransaction(){ 
            const token_auth = window.localStorage.token_auth;

          // console.log(array_msg.msg);
          transaction_Socket.send(JSON.stringify({
             'message': token_auth
          }));

      }
  }
};
```

the code above is working well, but my problem is a load of the transaction is to begging a little slow, every time the data is an increment

THE SECOND QUESTIONS

the code above to get all transaction and give it to all users, my question is how to give each transaction for one user like this example:

```
|user = 2                  
    buy = 23
    product = tv
    agent_id = 5
|user = 3        
    buy = 4
    product = fp
    agent_id = 7
|agent = 7  
    sell = 4
    product = somnting
```

and each user and agent has to dashboard, when I click in button in the real-time the code above, the transaction gives it all users, I have a SQL with a filter by agent_id, how to gives transactions for one agent the user and agent has different JWT tokens like this

```
|agent = 7 // DASHBOARD AGENT ID = 7
   user = 3
   buy = 4
   product = fp
   agent_id = 7

|agent = 5 // DASHBOARD AGENT ID = 5
   user = 2
   buy = 34
   product = somenting
   agent_id = 2
```

I guess you understand me, thank you attention
please help me.

Comment: What's the relation with django-rest-framework ?

Comment: because the def list_trans_all(), is getting a URL to form my other app restfull api and in this function called list_trans_all get all transaction